# jquery don't continue executing rest of javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first question on this site (but the other discussions have helped me).

In the following code:

```
$('#selObra').change(function() {
      var id_obra = $(this).val();
      if (id_obra == '-1') {
        //Elimino todos los renglones de la tabla
        $('#tblSubcontratos tbody tr').remove();
      } else {
        $('#tblSubcontratos').append('<tr><td class="center" colspan="6"><img src="images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif" height="16" width="16" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto" /></td></tr>');
        //Obtengo todos los contratos de la obra seleccionada
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'xml',
          url: 'get_subcontratos.php',
          data: 'id_obra=' + id_obra,
          success: function(xml) {
            $('#tblSubcontratos tbody tr').remove();
            if ($(xml).find('subcontratos').attr('status') == 'OK') {
              $(xml).find('subcontrato').each(function(){
                var id_subcontrato = $(this).find('id_subcontrato').text();
                var id_obra = $(this).find('id_obra').text();
                var nombre_obra = $(this).find('nombre_obra').text();
                var id_contratista = $(this).find('id_contratista').text();
                var nombre_contratista = $(this).find('nombre_contratista').text();
                var fecha_subcontrato = $(this).find('fecha_subcontrato').text();
                var strRow = '<tr class="ui-widget-content">' +
                               '<td>' + id_subcontrato + '</td>' +
                               '<td>' + nombre_obra + '</td>' +
                               '<td>' + nombre_contratista + '</td>' +
                               '<td>' + fecha_subcontrato + '</td>' +
                               '<td class="center view_details"><img src="images/view.gif" /></td>' +
                               '<td class="center"><input type="radio" name="subcontratoSeleccionado" /></td>' +
                             '</tr>';
                $('#tblSubcontratos tbody').append(strRow);
              });
            } else {
              var errno = $(xml).find('errno').text();
              var error = $(xml).find('error').text();
              $('#message').html(errno + ' - ' + error);
              $('#message').dialog('open');
            }
          }
        });
      }
      $("#divSubcontratos").dialog( "option", "position", 'center' );
    });
```

Centering the dialog is never executed... I can't see the mistake, the last line that firebug higlights is the bracket to close the else instruction... any comments will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Marco.

Comment: shouldn't you center it after the ajax response ends (whether successful or failed)?

Comment: Like Nico and RHSeeger told you, try put your dialog call `$("#divSubcontratos").dialog( "option", "position", 'center' );`, after `$('#tblSubcontratos tbody tr').remove();` (**Inside the ajax**) this should make the magic =) _PS: Welcome to Stackoverflow!!_ PS2: You can use the "Complete" option from ajax to call your dialog, if you want

Answer (score 0):

Two things I note:

- I see that you're calling dialog on #divSubcontratos, but I don't see that anywhere in the code. I'll assume it already exists at the point the code is being run, but it's worth mentioning
- As mentioned by Nico, you might want to move the command to center the div into the ajax callback, so you know it's all setup before it runs.

Comment: OK, thanks for all the comments... the case is that I want to center the dialog allways (when the user changes the selected oprion od the drop dwon box) the, that's why the center instruction is at the end, but I'll try to move to the suggested position. Thanks to everybody, this is one of the best sites to learn and to support in programming. BTW... how can I insert code when asking? This is because when I insert the code it was unformatted but someone formatted it for me (thanks!).